# ODBC Query with multiple conditions gives no results

Tags: c#, odbc, 4d-database

When querying a 4d database via an odbc system dsn, I am able to get back data from a statement with joins and a single, or no, where condition.

### This works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OdbcConnection sys4dConn = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=sys4dName");
        try
        {
            OdbcCommand getData = new OdbcCommand("
            SELECT
                Item.Client,
                CAST(Item.xref1 AS VARCHAR),
                CAST(Item.xref2 AS VARCHAR),
                CAST(Item.xref3 AS VARCHAR),
                CAST(Item.xref4 AS VARCHAR),
                Item.owner,
                Item.Storage_Date,
                Item.Temporary_Item_ID,
                Item.ItemType,
                Item.Item_Condition,
                Location.UnitName,
                Part.ConcatPosition,
                Part.Position1,
                Part.Position2,
                Part.Position3,
                Part.Position4,
                Part.Position5,
                Item.Comments,
                Part.Checked_Out_Reason,
                AuditTrail.ReasonforChange,
                '123abc' as CheckoutStatus 
            FROM
                Item 
                LEFT JOIN
                    Part 
                    ON Item.PK_ItemUID = Part.FK_ItemUID 
                LEFT JOIN
                    AuditTrail 
                    ON Part.PK_PartUID = AuditTrail.FK_PartUID 
                    AND 
                    (
                        Part.Position1 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Part.Position2 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Part.Position3 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Part.Position4 IS NOT NULL 
                        AND Part.Position5 IS NOT NULL 
                    )
                LEFT JOIN
                    Location 
                    ON Part.FK_UnitSectID = Location.PK_UnitSectID 
            WHERE
                Item.Client = '4468'", sys4dConn);

            getData.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OdbcDataAdapter daGetData = new OdbcDataAdapter(getData);

            using (DataTable dtTbl = new DataTable())
            {
                sys4dConn.Open();
                OdbcDataReader dr = getData.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DataRow dtRow = dtTbl.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtTbl.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        dtRow[i] = dr[i].ToString();
                    }
                    dtTbl.Rows.Add(dtRow);
                }
                sys4dName.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

(The query text has been formatted for this post. The actual string has only spaces, no carriage returns or line feeds.)

### This also works:

```
         ...WHERE
                Item.Client IN ('4468')", sys4dConn);
```

With each of the above, the query returns 12 rows of data.
If I change the client to '7147', I get 14 rows of data.

When I want to pull both in one dataset, though, I get zero rows.

### None of these work:

```
         ...WHERE
                Item.Client = '4468'
                OR Item.Client = '7147'", sys4dConn);


         ...WHERE
                Item.Client IN ('4468','7147')", sys4dConn);


         ...WHERE
                Item.Client = ?
                OR Item.Client = ?", sys4dConn);
            getData.Parameters.AddWithValue("client", "4468");
            getData.Parameters.AddWithValue("client", "7147");
```

The last one throws the following:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> > Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**Is there some syntax that will allow me to include more than one condition in the `where` clause of my odbc query?**

A version of the query with all of the joins removed does return the 26 rows using

```
         ...WHERE
                Item.Client = '4468'
                OR Item.Client = '7147'", sys4dConn);
```

Comment: Have you tried your query from inside of the 4D application to confirm it works as expected there? Here is a tech tip that talks about this troubleshooting step in the context PDO_4D but it could also apply to your situation of using C#. http://kb.4d.com/assetid=76287

Comment: Also, if you wanted to remove ODBC from the equation you could try using the native C Library: https://github.com/4D/SQLlib_4D

Comment: @TimPenner I license a third party application that uses the 4d-db. I don't think I have access to the 4D Method Editor. Is there a way around this that will allow me to query the db?